# fail to use google tag manager to track analytic data

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to use Google Tag Manager to track Google Analytic data. However, I can not see any data tracked on Google Analytic as I have followed the instructions on the Google Tag Manager page.

So I would like to know if any part of my codes or configuration of the tag manager go wrong.

```
TagManager tagManager = TagManager.getInstance(this);
    tagManager.setVerboseLoggingEnabled(true);
    PendingResult<ContainerHolder> pending = tagManager.loadContainerPreferNonDefault(CONTAINER_ID, R.raw.gtm_xxxxxx);
    pending.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContainerHolder>(){
        @Override
        public void onResult(ContainerHolder containerHolder) {
            ContainerHolderSingleton.setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
            DataLayer dataLayer = TagManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getDataLayer();
            dataLayer.pushEvent("openScreen", DataLayer.mapOf("screenName", "MainScreen"));
            Log.d(TAG, "push event");
        }

    }, 2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Below are my configuration of Google Tag Manager web panel.

[tag, trigger and variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MTPe.jpg)

I know there are hours of delay for Google Analytic. However, I have been implementing the Google Tag Manager for days and still no data are tracked. Also, I still have 0 real time user in Analytic page.

Comment: after looking at the network usage of the application, i found that there is network data transfer only for refreshing the container but not dispatching hits. And I still not yet find the cause of this and I will keep update this if I find any solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of answer searching, i found that the problem is about the setting of Google Tag Manager.

In the "fields to set" of Tags, field name of screen name variable is not correct. It should not be a variable, instead, it should be a text only.